# Microsoft Access Form entering data. (Skill Matrix)

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

I am very new to Microsoft access. I am trying to create a form that allows a team member to enter their Fn, Ln, and the team they are on. Then, go through each "Skill" and then fill in their competency on that particular skill. I am having trouble with the skill part because there are a lot of skills under one "Skill Category" (See my images). After this, they just press submit and the data goes to my "Skill Matrix" table. I would just like feedback, maybe my table designs are bad. Thank you.

[image: Relationship table.]
[image: Updated Form.]

Comment: Table relationships look ok. Although probably should have a Teams table. This is where TeamLeader name should go. I am not sure about form design. Exactly what is the RecordSource for the subform? Should be Matrix table. A combobox should be used to select skill. What is code in the button? Record is committed to table when: 1) table/query/form is closed; or 2) move to another record; or 3) run code to save.

Comment: @june7. I have watched a couple of tutorial videos and made some headway. I guess my question is how to connect all these fields and once i press submit that record is saved. Right now, there isn't code on the button, I am still trying to figure out how to bind combo boxes to fields in the Matrix, that way it enters into the database correctly. I submitted a new picture on my progress. Also, I have so many skills... Won't that be tedious to pick a skill and rate it and enter one at a time, for a person? Is there a better way? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, data entry can be a tedious process. That's what clerks are for. The more 'user friendly' you want an app to be, the more code. User can select a Category and code can create records in Matrix for the member for all skills associated with that Category. This would be an INSERT SELECT action SQL executed in VBA. Although that may speed up the process, code cannot do the rating. Someone still has to visit each record and enter the Competency.